# website inserting pics

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello i am getting this error message :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 7:  
Line 8:      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Line 9:          UserIdValue.Text = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()
Line 10:         cannotUploadImageMessage.Visible = False
Line 11:     End Sub
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Seems Membership.GetUser() is null or Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey is null, just check for null.

Comment: Or the controls `cannotUploadImageMessage` or `UserIdValue` do not exist at that stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty straightforward error to debug. The error message should tell you exactly which line it's on (either 9 or 10). It's just a matter of setting a breakpoint on that line and running the page, then working out which object hasn't been set by hovering your mouse over each object.